# Pandas Delete rows from dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Consider this code:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = """a, RR
10, 1asas
20, 1asasas
30,
40, asas
50, ayty
60, 2asas
80, 3asas"""
frame = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), skipinitialspace=True)

print frame,"\n\n\n"

l=[]
for i,j in frame[~ frame['RR'].str.startswith("1", na=True)]['RR'].iteritems():
    if j.startswith(('2','3')):
         if frame[frame['RR'].str.startswith("1", na=False)]['RR'].str.match("1"+j[1:], as_indexer = True).any():
            l.append(i)
    else:
        if frame[frame['RR'].str.startswith("1", na=False)]['RR'].str.match("1"+j, as_indexer = True).any():
            l.append(i)
 frame = frame.drop(frame.index[l])
 print frame
```

What i am doing here is,

1)Loop through dataframes to drop any `RR` which already has `1RR` in dataframe

2)If `RR` has `2 or 3` at start , then drop if that `RR` has `1RR[1:]` in dataframe.

3)If `RR` startswith `1` or is `NaN` do not touch it.

The code is working fine but this `dataframe` will have upto 1 million entries and i dont think this code is optimsed.As i have just started with `pandas` i have limited knowledge.
Is there any way we can achieve this without `iteration`.Does `pandas` has any inbuilt utility to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `1RR`?

Comment: @IanS the string `1` + `RR` like we have here `asas` and also `1asas` so that `asas` will be dropped

Comment: I don't have time for a fully-fledged answer, but this code could point you in the right direction: `series1 = frame.loc[frame['RR'].str.startswith("1", na=False), 'RR']; frame.loc[(frame['RR'].str.startswith("2")) | (frame['RR'].str.startswith("3")), 'RR'].str.slice(1).isin(series1.str.slice(1))` (deals with your second condition).

Comment: @IanS gr8!!!! thanx....will look for 1st condition.....but this will return the whole new frame rt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, keep all strings starting with `1` or `nan`:

```
keep = frame['RR'].str.startswith("1", na=True)
keep1 = keep[keep]  # will be used at the end
```

**Second**, keep strings starting with `2` or `3` that are not in the first dataframe `rr1`:

```
rr1 = frame.loc[frame['RR'].str.startswith("1", na=False), 'RR']
keep2 = ~frame.loc[
            (frame['RR'].str.startswith("2")) | (frame['RR'].str.startswith("3")), 'RR'
        ].str.slice(1).isin(rr1.str.slice(1))
```

**Third**, keep other strings that are not in `rr1` after adding a leading `1`:

```
import numpy as np
keep3 = ~("1" + frame.loc[
            ~frame['RR'].str.slice(0,1).isin([np.nan, "1", "2", "3"]), 'RR'
        ]).isin(rr1)
```

**Finally**, put everything together:

```
frame[pd.concat([keep1, keep2, keep3]).sort_index()]
```

Comment: We can have 2 approaches ... the one you do or we can use the other one where we can `drop` rows from existing frame.Which of the 2 would be good here?

Comment: I don't think there is any practical difference between the two.